# Json custom template using Play Twirl in Java

Tags: json, templates, playframework, deadbolt-2

I am trying to create a Play custom template to return json using Twirl and am unable to find any solid examples for the same. 
Is there any other way in play to render a view with JSON and implement deadbolt on views if not twirl templating?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Twirl without a problem.  Have you seen the [custom format guide](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCustomTemplateFormat)?  Also, take a look at [play.twirl.api.Formats](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/50dd0faf684c26ea60672b5f389c42badf555d9c/api/shared/src/main/scala/play/twirl/api/Formats.scala) to see how XML, etc, is implemented.

For example, here's the implementation of Play's built-in XML Twirl format.

```
class Xml private (elements: immutable.Seq[Xml], text: String) extends BufferedContent[Xml](elements, text) {
  def this(text: String) = this(Nil, Formats.safe(text))
  def this(elements: immutable.Seq[Xml]) = this(elements, "")

  /**
   * Content type of XML (`application/xml`).
   */
  def contentType = MimeTypes.XML
}

/**
 * Helper for XML utility methods.
 */
object Xml {

  /**
   * Creates an XML fragment with initial content specified.
   */
  def apply(text: String): Xml = {
    new Xml(text)
  }

}

/**
 * Formatter for XML content.
 */
object XmlFormat extends Format[Xml] {

  /**
   * Creates an XML fragment.
   */
  def raw(text: String) = Xml(text)

  /**
   * Creates an escaped XML fragment.
   */
  def escape(text: String) = Xml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(text))

  /**
   * Generate an empty XML fragment
   */
  val empty: Xml = new Xml("")

  /**
   * Create an XML Fragment that holds other fragments.
   */
  def fill(elements: immutable.Seq[Xml]): Xml = new Xml(elements)
}
```

Because you can do this in Twirl, you can use the existing Deadbolt templates as they are.  If you choose to go with a non-Twirl implementation, you can just re-implement the Deadbolt templates you need because all the logic is actually handled outside the templates.  Take a look at [be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ViewSupport](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/ViewSupport.java) or [be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.ViewSupport](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/ViewSupport.scala) - for example, the `dynamic` template just accepts some parameters and passes them directly to `ViewSupport`.

```
@if(viewSupport.dynamic(name, meta, handler, timeout(), request)) {
   @body
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Will try to implement as you suggested.